# Resetting a active directory user password in a forest

Tags: c#, active-directory

I build a class based on this code: [Everything in Active Directory via C#.NET 3.5 (Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement) - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-Using?msg=5101732#xx5101732xx). It works perfectly in my scenario. However, recently, we have restructured our domain setup and this time, there is a Global Catalog involved and a complex distribution of active directory users. Here is a rough diagram:

[image: Forest]

Now, I have been trying very hard to stay on the PrincipleContext APIs and amange the requirements but it seems that I'm missing something. Requirements are simple:

**An AD user will be able to validate his own credentials:** This is accomplished like so:

```
    public string AuthenticateUsingPrincipalcontext(string strDomain, string strUserName, string strPassword)
    {
        string strDistinguishedName;
        var strPath = string.Empty;

        PrincipalContext ctx = null;

        var domainArr = strDomain.Split('.');

        strPath = domainArr.Aggregate(strPath, (current, strDc) => current + $"DC={strDc},");

        if (strPath.EndsWith(","))
        {
            strPath = strPath.Substring(0, strPath.Length - 1);
        }

        try
        {
            ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strDomain + ":3268", strPath, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing, strUserName, strPassword);

            var bValid = ctx.ValidateCredentials(strUserName, strPassword);

            // Additional check to search user in directory.
            if (bValid)
            {
                var prUsr = new UserPrincipal(ctx) {SamAccountName = strUserName};

                var searchUser = new PrincipalSearcher(prUsr);
                var foundUsr = searchUser.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;

                if (foundUsr != null)
                {
                    strDistinguishedName = foundUsr.DistinguishedName;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new AuthenticationException("Please enter valid UserName/Password.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new AuthenticationException("Please enter valid UserName/Password.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Authentication Error in PrincipalContext. Message: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            ctx?.Dispose();
        }

        return strDistinguishedName;
    }
```

Note that I'm appending  `":3268"` to the domain name while creating the principle context. That enforces a GLobal Catalog service to-go. However, in absence of a global catalog (non-forest), it still works.

**An AD user can change his password:** I'm assuming I'll be able to do this as well.

**An AD user's password need to be reset using a technical user:** This is where the issues start. If I cook up a PrincipleContext using the technical user's info sitting in *eu.company.com* (and can see all users across all controllers), I cannot use that to reset a password of a user on, say, *me.company.com* or *company-abc.com*